# When to leave a postdoc as foreigner that doesn't have enough courage because of current global situation?

Tags: united-states, postdocs, covid-19

so i joined a postdoc in US six months back. Had to move from India. Even after six months have no clue what im working on how to proceed with work. I make suggestions to the PI but he shoots them down. He is making me work but nothing productive which can translate into research paper in the next year. He is always early in the lab and leaves in the evening and expects us to be there during the time he is in the lab. Should i leave or stick it out?

Comment: You haven't given any reason to stay and several to leave. What are you asking?

Comment: Is it okay to leave so soon? Am i being paranoid or shld these things not bother me?

Comment: It seems normal to be bothered, actually. I hope you have some other options.

Comment: No currently i dont. Havent even started looking yet cz im new in this country and dont have the courage to make the move again

Comment: Would moving cause any problems with your visa?

Comment: Very generally speaking, it's often not a good idea to leave a position until you have another secured. There are exceptions when it is necessary to get out of a situation where serious harm is ongoing or imminent, but that doesn't describe your situation.

Answer (score 2):

Though I empathise with your situation, I don't gather from your description what you have been actively doing to make the situation better. You said you don't have the courage to move, so I understand that you might also not have been speaking up.

Do not do that. Do speak up, while being polite, and do try to improve your situation. Have you, for instance, had a conversation yet with your boss? Does he allow you to change research direction if you would think that would be helpful? Can you bring up your own ideas that you would be more excited about?

Though I don't think that one should stay endlessly in a position which does not offer a perspective and there are certainly places worth leaving, be aware that you will encounter issues during every postdoc. You do have to be able to develop the tools to cope with these and carve out your own path successfully.

Do not worry too much about others opinions when deciding to leave, it happens and people know that. Be smart about it, however, and do not talk negatively about this situation to a potential future lab.